# PEM_read_PrivateKey failed

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to use ssh to log in to AWS from OSX Mavericks and having a hell of a time:

I enter:

> ssh -i ~/.ssh/filename.pem ec2-user@ec2-xx-x-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com -v

And I get this, as well as a keychain popup that asks for a password, even though there is none to give...

> debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
>   debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
>   Saving password to keychain failed.

I launched a new instance on AWS and generated a new key pair. When I left the .pem file unprotected, the OSX keychain popup didn't appear, but I was unable to access AWS because the file was unprotected:

> Permissions 0644 for '/Users/cvn/.ssh/chris-test.pem' are too open. It
>   is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
>   This private key will be ignored. bad permissions: ignore key:
>   /Users/cvn/.ssh/chris-test.pem Permission denied (publickey).

So I ran

> chmod 400 chris-test.pem

and the Keychain returned asking for a password that I do not have...

Comment: What command did you use to generate your key pair? Are you sure you didn't protect the private key .pem with a password? It's bad form to store private keys unencrypted, so you probably did give it a password.

Comment: On second thought, from that error message, maybe it's trying to store your private key in your OS X keychain, but your keychain is locked so it needs your keychain password to unlock it so it can store your private key there.

Comment: Hi Spiff - Thanks for the ideas. I've tried fixing this (see above) and no luck so far...

Comment: Figured this out. It was a screwed RSA file. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I by mistake used public key instead of private one.